# {javascript} JS code run in unexpected way

Tags: javascript

I got this issue when learning js:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tyfE.png)

Here is my code:

```
9.  console.log(obj);
10. var obj = {id:123, name:'abc'};
11. obj.age = 23;
12. console.log(obj);
13. obj.class = 23433;
```

I thought it shows #9 -- undefined and #12 -- {id:123, name:'abc'}

However it shows #9 -- {id: 123, name: "abc", age: 23, class: 23433} and #12 -- {id:123, name:'abc'}

I don't understand how js run. Can anyone explain this or what js feature I should study?

Comment: You must have run this multiple times, so maybe it shows you the value from last run.

Comment: #9 shows undefined like you expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refresh the page, and let every lines run. Line #9 outputs `undefined`, and line 12 ouputs `Object {id: 123, name: "abc", age: 23}` as you expected.

Line #9 doesn't throw Reference error because of "hoisting" (you can check out what "hoisting" is)